# What does #^ do?

Tags: clojure

I have looked through Clojure documentation and at source code, however I cannot find the meaning of `#^`.

What does `#^` do in the following, and where is it documented?

```
(defn- parse-headers [#^HttpResponse http-resp]
  (into {} (map (fn [#^Header h] [(.toLowerCase (.getName h)) (.getValue h)])
            (iterator-seq (.headerIterator http-resp)))))
```

Comment: @WolfeFan My answer was wrong... I'll happily delete it myself.

Comment: @MichaelT: thanks! I apologize for the harshness; I was just annoyed that a wrong answer was getting upvoted while my correct answer got a downvote.

Comment: see this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645514/clojure-syntax-question-re

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just supposed to be a type hint, which is usually signified by ^TypeName before the parameter name in a function's parameter list. I'm not sure what the difference is between ^ and #^; maybe it's older syntax?

Comment: Actually, it looks like valid Type hint syntax. I'm not sure why you'd use one over the other.

Comment: Down voter: explain, please?

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) - You might want to expand the answer with additional information that backs up the type hint information and shows its usage (and why one would do it).  Ideally, answers don't ask questions either.

Comment: @MichaelT Good points. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: +1 `#^` is the old syntax for type hinting